Are questions on how much Bitcoin does a person/business have fair game?
Should questions like "How much revenue Mezza Grill generated?" and the yet to be asked "How much Bitcoin does Mt. Gox have?" fair play?
I did ask the question about Mezza Grill, but in second thought I think such questions add little value to the site and should be off topic. What do you think?

On first take, they appear to have no long-term value:

they could quickly become obsolete
this isn't a problem that anyone is looking to solve

So I'd tend to close them as "Not constructive." 

Funny, I'd more than tend to do that, I'd do that as a rule. :)

Agreed, however there are some important issues peculiar to bitcoin such as the large publicly visible accounts owned by the inventor, and others.  There are some legitimate concerns regarding these accounts and what cashing them out might mean to bitcoin.

I'd say that it's a judgement call, but I agree with Dori's bullet points as the terms of that judgement. If, for example, someone was asking how many coins were pre-mined on IXCoin by that fork's founder then the data will 1) not become obsolete and 2) clearly expresses a concern or problem that someone is looking to solve (i.e. "should I use IXC since someone mined tens of thousands of coins before even releasing it). I'd "tend" to close as "not constructive" too but I can see where there might be exceptions.

What could be a bigger question for a business considering adopting Bitcoins than how effective it has been for other companies that have done so? I agree that open-ended, vague, or fixed in time questions aren't constructive. But a more focused question like "Did Meza Grill experience an increase in business when they started accepting Bitcoins?" seems both on-topic and constructive to me.
I would make the same argument for questions like "How were the first Bitcoins mined before Bitcoin was well-known? Do we know who holds them, or held them, and how many?"

By temporally limiting your question with "when they started accepting bitcoins" and posing a definitively answerable question I think you've qualified as an exception according to Dori's bullet points since your answer will neither become obsolete and aims to solve a problem.
